# Shared TitleView in Xamarin.Forms AppShell

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Is there a way to implement a shared TitleView component in Xamarin.Forms AppShell? I've tried a couple of approaches but it's not working as I intended.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the following:

- App Shell with a few tabs and a common Shell TitleView
- The titleView is just a ContentView (let's call it Exposure) with a label to display the result of a calculation and a refresh button to fetch data and recalculate
- Changing Tab shouldn't affect the state of the TitleView

What I've tried:

- Initialize one instance of the Exposure component (View and ViewModel) and configure it on the DI framework to use that instance only (singleton).
- When the Pages are initialized I get the single instance of the Exposure component and assign it to the Shell.TitleView property.

By doing this I was hoping that the Exposure state would be consistent across the tabs (single instance after all...), but what happens is that when I hit the refresh button it only refreshes the calculation on the current tab Exposure component, changing tab will present me with the Exposure component with old state. I'm surprised this is not supported out of the box (configure titleView at Shell level) but I might be missing something.

Might not be relevant but I'm using ReactiveUI (MVVM) and Splat (dependency injection)

The next thing I'm willing to try is to trigger a refresh when each page re-appears but that feels dodgy.

Comment: Generally I think you want to avoid making views/viewmodels singletons. However, if you were to register a singleton service that will maintain the state of your calculation, inject that into your VM's, then data bind to the view, state will be maintained on the singleton service, and shared across the views and viewmodels which should be registered as transient.

Comment: @MaxHampton Right that makes sense and seems to be a much better pattern. I actually have a singleton for the service that maintains the state with raw data and then the viewmodel transforms it slightly, but I can probably shape things differently for not having to use a singleton component (view+viewmodel).

Comment: If you're using ReactiveUI then have a look at DynamicData (https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) for the data service, they sit quite nicely together.

Comment: @PaulCharlton Thanks. I'm already using that actually, but only on the ViewModel (using SourceCache) but perhaps I need to use it one layer above on the actual service that fetches the data. I'm quite new to ReactiveUI so I'm still dabbling and refactoring stuff all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base ContentPage and set the style of **TitleView** of it .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="xxx.BaseContentPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            //...
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            //...
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the style isn't the problem. It's the state that's not being maintained when I switch tabs. I think I'd have exactly the same issue with the approach you suggested. I'm willing to give it a try tho, if that works with Shell (not sure if shell plays well with NavigationPage)

Comment: Of course you can also use ResourceDictionary , but it only allow you to set basic property(such as color of button and background color of navigation bar ) .

Comment: that's still style (which I don't have issues with)

Comment: Did you test my solution?

Comment: Zhang Yes and it didn't work for me without me doing some tweaks. I had to inject a singleton ViewModel into the BaseContentPage so that all components based on that would share the same state. As-is your answer is not complete enough for me to accept it.

Comment: My post is just a demo to show you the solution . And you can edit my answer ,Which will help more people .